# parsing a string which has parenthesis and comma seperated values

Tags: c++, regex, string, parsing

i have a string like this:

```
string astr = "a(b,c,u),d,e(f),g(),h,i(j(k,l,m(n))),r";
```

- a contains b,c,u
- e contains f
- i contains j
- j contains k,l,m
- m contains n
- r contains nothing

you can think this as a file system
on the input letters which has () is folders
 
remains are the files
whats correct way to parse this string
 
regex , stack function or simple string parse functions  ? and how ?

Comment: A loop and a stack to keep track of how nested you are should be sufficient.

Comment: If you want the result in a list, a recursive call stack with a non-local list is the way to go.

Comment: Just enter a new funtion call whenever you find ' (', and make sure you exit on ')'.   It's not rocket science.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think simple stack and string methods would be enough
go through every character on string 
make a stack named url
when you see "(" ")" or "," character parse it 
when you see "(" character push the x(  x to stack
when you see ")" character pop the stack

and you will have a token with its url to where it belongs